# render_views error when testing API controller with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to testing and rspec in particular. I'm trying to test the index action on a controller we built for an API.

The controller itself is in ../app/controllers/my_api/api_controller.rb

../spec/controllers/my_api/api_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyApi::ApiController do
  render_views 

  describe 'GET index' do

    it 'returns a list of all available API endpoints'  do
        get :index, :format => :json
        response.should be_success
    end

  end


end
```

After running the test I get the following error:

```
api_controller_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `render_views' for #<Class:0x007ffafd532a78> (NameError)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13844409/17773

Comment: If not, also paste the contents of your spec_helper.rb file, and specify which versions of rails & rspec/rspec-rails you're using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [render\_views returning NoMethodError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840602/render-views-returning-nomethoderror)